# Why undefined behavior is so consistent?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, undefined-behavior

I've been playing with pointers and accidentally typed the wrong argument to printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
  double * p1;
  double * p2; 
  double d1, d2;

  d1 = 1.2345;
  d2 = 2.3456;
  p1 = &d1;
  p2 = &d2;

  printf ("p1=%p\n, *p1=%g\n", (void *)p1, *p1);
  printf ("p2=%p\n, *p2=%g\n", (void *)p2,  p2); /* third argument should be *p2 */

  return 0;
}
```

The output was

> warning: format ‘%g’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘double *’
>   p1=0x7ffc9aec46b8, *p1=1.2345
>   p2=0x7ffc9aec46c0, *p2=1.2345

Why in this case the output of `p2` is always equal to the output of `*p1`?

I use gcc (v5.4.0) compiler with its default standard for C (gnu11).

Comment: Undefined behaviour means there is no guarantee it will have a specific behaviour on any platform under any conditions.  It does not have any implications about whether you will observe consitent behaviour between successive runs.

Comment: It isn't defined just because it doesn't change for each program run.

Comment: it isn't defined by the language spec, but compilers can do whatever they like.

Comment: This example is yet another very good reason to compile with all warnings enabled, then fix those warnings before trying to run the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's **not** defined -- that's the whole point. What you're seeing is likely the result of the old value remaining in whatever register is used for passing a floating-point argument.

Comment: Thanks, that's the case. I've tried to pass a pointer to another floating-point value (not 1.2345) before the last printf statement and the value of p2 in the output changed from 1.2345 to that other value.

Answer (score 6):

Code that invokes undefined behavior can do anything -- that's why it's *undefined*.

That said, one could make a good guess at why it happens to do *this particular thing* on *your particular machine* using *your specific compiler* with *exactly the options you used* and compiled on the *same weekday of a year with a 6*, you get the point, right? It's **undefined**, and there is **no explanation** that you can rely on even if you think you know all the variables. One day, the humidity drops, or something, and your program could decide to do something different. Even without recompiling. Even in two iterations of the same loop. That's just what undefined behavior is.

Anyway, on your platform floating-point arguments are probably passed in dedicated floating-point registers (or a dedicated floating-point stack) rather than on the main stack. printf("%g") expects a floating-point argument, so it looks in a floating-point register. But you didn't pass anything in a floating-point register; all you passed were two pointer arguments, which both went on the stack (or wherever pointer arguments go; this is also outside the scope of the C standard). So the second printf call gets whatever garbage was in that particular floating point register last time it was loaded. It just so happens that the last thing you loaded into that register was the value of `*p1`, in the last printf call, so that value gets reused.

The rules that determine (among other things) where function arguments are placed so the function knows where to look for them are collectively called a *calling convention*. You're probably using an x86 or derivative, so you might find the [Wikipedia page on x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) interesting. But if you want to know specifically what your compiler is doing, ask it to emit assembly language (gcc -S).

Answer (score 4):

At language level there's usually little value in this kind of research.

But one possible practical scenario might look as follows:

The compiler uses different passing conventions (memory areas, stacks, registers) to pass different types of arguments. Pointers are passed in one way (say, CPU stack), while `double` values are passed in a different way (say, FPU register stack). You passed a pointer, but told `printf` that it was a `double`. `printf` went into the area for passing `double`s (e.g., top of FPU register stack) and read the "garbage" value that was left over there by the previous `printf` call.

Answer (score 3):

> undefined behavior - there are no restrictions on the behavior of the
>   program. Examples of undefined behavior are memory accesses outside of
>   array bounds, signed integer overflow, null pointer dereference,
>   modification of the same scalar more than once in an expression
>   without sequence points, access to an object through a pointer of a
>   different type, etc. Compilers are not required to diagnose undefined
>   behavior (although many simple situations are diagnosed), and the
>   compiled program is not required to do anything meaningful.[1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Undefined behavior doesn't mean random behavior, but "not covered by the standard" behavior. So it may be anything the implementator chooses to do with it.

The standard specifies UBs because it allows for compilation optimizations that might not be possible otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have covered what undefined behaviour is. Here's an interesting article that describes **why** there is so much undefined behaviour in C, and what the benefits may be. It's not because K&R were lazy or didn't care.

http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

In short, undefined behaviour and implementation-defined behaviour can open opportunities for optimisation, and for more efficient implementation on different platforms.

Comment: That article describes the misguided philosophy that has led compiler writers to demand that things staying undefined, but think don't think at accurately describes why they were left undefined in C89.  Prior to C89, many behaviors were defined on some platforms but not others, and I've seen no evidence that the authors of C89 intended to change that.  For many actions that invoke UB, letting an implementation do absolutely anything offers little optimization benefit over granting it the freedom to pick in arbitrary fashion from among a choice of possible behaviors.

Comment: Do you know of any evidence that the authors of C89 were intending to allow the kinds of "optimization" that modern compilers use to justify forcing programmers to write less-efficient code?

Comment: @supercat: I'm not sure I understand your question. Implementation-defined behaviour is still well-defined behaviour. It means that the compiler writer has to account for and handle that particular case. In some cases this is what you want but in many cases it can be at odds with efficiency. If you want to make the point that things were different before 1989, perhaps you could provide an example?

Comment: Reading the rationale for C89, I think it's pretty clear that the decision to make unsigned short values promote to "signed int" was predicated in some measure on the fact that it would not affect the behavior of code like [assume 16-bit "short" and 32-bit "int"] `unsigned mul(unsigned short x, unsigned short y) { return x*y; }` on modern platforms, even in cases where the product is between INT_MAX+1 and UINT_MAX (they explicitly mention such cases).  Do you think the authors would have intended that a function like that should have completely unpredictable side-effects?

Comment: Also, in applications where it is acceptable to have a program do *almost* anything when given invalid input, including producing meaningless results or terminating abnormally, but where some conceivable behaviors (execute arbitrary code supplied by creator of maliciously-malformed input) would be unacceptable, does it make sense that the C code necessary to meet such loose requirements should be more cumbersome than machine code to do so?  If overflow were Implementation-Defined, that would require that `int1*int2>long1` behave consistent in its choice of yielding 1 or 0 in case of overflow.

Comment: It's good that the authors didn't want to impose such a requirement, since on many implementations the most efficient method of evaluation might depend upon context.  On the other hand, on commonplace platforms, requiring that the expression never do anything other than yield 0, yield 1, or terminate the program should cost nothing outside contrived situations.  Do you think the authors of the Standard intended that programmers who would be equally happy with any of those outcomes in case of overflow should be required to force a compiler's choice of evaluation method?

Answer (score 0):

The C language was in wide use well before the C89 Standard was published, and the authors of the Standard did not want to require that conforming compilers not be able to do everything existing compilers could do as efficiently as they were already doing it.  If mandating that all compilers implement some behavior would make some compiler somewhere less suitable for its task, that would be justification for leaving the behavior undefined.  Even if the behavior was useful, and in common use, on 99% of platforms, the authors of the Standard saw no reason to believe that leaving the behavior undefined should affect that.  If compiler writers thought it was practical and useful to support a behavior in the days before any Standard mandated anything, there was no reason to expect that they'd need a mandate in order to maintain such support.  Evidence of that view can be found in the rationale about promoting short unsigned integer types to signed.

Somehow a bizarre view has taken hold that everything must either be mandated by the Standard or unpredictable.  The Standard describes common consequences of Undefined Behavior, and one of the most common in 1989 was that the implementation will behave in a documented fashion characteristic to the implementation.

If your implementation specifies the means via which floating-point values are passed to variadic functions, and if the method it uses is to create a temporary and pass its address, then the behavior of your code *might* be defined on that particular implementation, in which case it would hardly be surprising that it works as it does.  If the implementation handles arguments that way but doesn't document them well enough to guarantee the behavior, it should hardly be surprising that the implementation's behavior isn't affected by the lack of documentation.